# No entiendo la necesidad de que un metodo retorne la clase con parametros

Tags: python, poo

```
class Punto():

    def __init__(self,x , y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def restar(self, nuevo):
        #nace nuevo vector
        return Punto(self.x - nuevo.x, self.y - nuevo.y)

    def norma(self):
        #convierto a entero o decimal
        return (self.x * self.x + self.y * self.y)**0.5

    def distancia(self, nuevo):
        #distancia entre puntos
        r = self.restar(nuevo)
        return r.norma()

 p = Punto(5,7)
 q = Punto(2,3)
 r = p.restar(q)
 print (r.x, r.y)
 print (r.norma())
 print (q.distancia(r))
```

En el método `restar` no entiendo la última línea, ¿por qué hago `return Punto(self.x - nuevo.x, self.y - nuevo.y)` esta bien 
y al hacerlo así `return (self.x - nuevo.x, self.y - nuevo.y)` me sale el siguiente error:

> line 29 in 
>   print (r.x, r.y)
>   AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'x'

El error hace referencia a la linea 29 la cual es `print (r.x, r.y)` pero
al agregar "Punto" en la función restar se soluciona.

Comment: Es una clase, quedo por fuera del bloque de codigo, en la parte superior dice class Punto(): y continua hacia abajo el codigo, gracias colegas

Comment: Cuando retornas `Punto(...)` entonces tienes un objeto tipo Punto, lo cual sí tiene dentro de sus atributos un elemento `x` y un elemento `y`. Sin embargo, si retornas sin el `Punto` antes del paréntesis, estarías retornando una tupla (termina siendo `(3,4)`), lo cual es más similar a una lista (o array) que a tu clase `Punto`, por lo que no puedes operar sobre la `r`  con las funciones de un `Punto` cuando es una tupla

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Entiendo yo que la idea es:

1. Un objeto de la clase `Punto` implementa un método `restar`
2. Este método permite restar un `Punto` con otro `Punto`
3. El resultado es un nuevo objeto `Punto` con distintas coordenadas `x` e `y`.

#### ¿Por qué hago `return Punto(self.x - nuevo.x, self.y - nuevo.y)`?

Simplemente creas un nuevo objeto `Punto` cuyas coordenadas son las del objeto actual menos las del nuevo y es lo que retornas. Por ejemplo:

```
p1 = Punto(5, 10)
p2 = Punto(5, 10)
p3 = p1.restar(p2)

print("Nuevo punto: ({0},{1})".format(p3.x, p3.y))

> Nuevo punto: (0,0)
```

Aclaración al titulo de tu pregunta: el método no retorna una clase, lo que retorna es un objeto instanciado de la clase `Punto`.

#### ¿Y por que el error al hacer `return (self.x - nuevo.x, self.y - nuevo.y)`?

Por que estás haciendo algo totalmente distinto, en vez de retornar un objeto `Punto`, estas retornando una `tupla` entonces cuando haces esto:

```
r = p.restar(q)
print (r.x, r.y)
```

`r` ya no es un `Punto` y no tiene los atributos `x` e `y` que define la clase `Punto`, de ahí el error:

> line 29 in print (r.x, r.y) AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no
> attribute 'x'